# How Elatic Beanstalk Worker and Elastic Beanstal Rails API work together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I recently work on a project. The project is built using ruby ​​on rails and AWS services. I am a novice in this area, so I still can't understand many things.

The project contains an elastic beanstal (EB) for Rails API and a EB for Job workers. Both EBs use the same code to deploy. It seems that this structure is conventional, but because I am a novice, I don't understand why two separate EBs should be used. Why can't the function of Job worker be put in API EB?

IN addtion, how did API EB and Job worker EB establish a connection? When sending a request to API EB, what mechanism does Job Worker EB use to respond?

Thanks

Comment: EB web and EB worker types work in a totally different way and have different use-cases. Does you current application already use the two types or you want to design it to use both types?

Comment: Already use the two types.